# How to put chips into textfields in vuetify? / How to create hashtags ( in textfields)?

Tags: vue.js, textfield, vuetify.js, hashtag

I'm trying to include chips into textfields, so that you got chips next to normal text like in social media. I'm basically trying to implement hashtags in vuetify textfields also using '#' to start a chip.

Here's what i got so far.

https://codepen.io/issabln/pen/WLzrLG

```
 <v-combobox 
                multiple
                v-model="select" 
                  :items="select"
                label="LABEL" 
                placeholder="tags"
                small-chips
                deletable-chips
              :search-input.sync="search" 
                @keyup.tab="updateTags"
                @paste="updateTags">
      </v-combobox>
```

(It's more. please click the link)

I want to put that into an input / textarea tag. 
like:

```
<v-input> <tag></tag> </v-input>
```

So only if I hit an # before a word, it shall make it into a chip.

Comment: please share what you have tried so far

Comment: Like @BoussadjraBrahim mentioned. Create some codepin sample code

Comment: you could refer to this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54097082/8172857) to create a sample running snippet

Comment: I added some code

Comment: Hello @Apbln take alook at [THIS](https://codepen.io/virtualadrian/pen/pOeVPX)