# Missing a default scoped slot Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am looking at the tutorials on vues page for adding tooltips. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips

It seems to work fine for an individual button.

However, it does not work within a v-item.  I get a console message saying

> '[Vuetify] v-item is missing a default scopedSlot'

```
<v-item v-for="foo in bars" :key=`${foo}`>
  <v-tooltip>
    <v-btn slot="activator">
      <v-icon>some-icon</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <span>Some tooltip text</span>
  </v-tooltip>
</v-item>
```

I've tried adding things to the above code like slot="activator" to v-item and slot-scope="activator" to the v-btn, but nothing seems to work quite right. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Running snippet added by @BoussadjraBrahim :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      bars: ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<div id="app">
  <v-item-group>
    <v-container grid-list-md>
      <v-layout wrap>
        <v-flex v-for="(n,i) in bars" :key="n" xs12 md4>
          <v-item>
            <v-tooltip>
              <v-btn slot="activator">
                <v-icon>home</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
              <span>Some tooltip text {{n}}</span>
            </v-tooltip>
          </v-item>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-item-group>

</div>
```

Comment: please reproduce your code [`here`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OrEGqd?editors=1011) in order to debug it

Comment: It looks like you've already added it to that link. Thanks!

Comment: i was looking that you add the missing parts

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. The only thing to add would be to point to a real v-icon like the 'home' one you used

Comment: i'm trying to find a solution, so add that pen to your question in order the others could help you easily

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim why are you suggesting using CodePens instead of Runnable Snippets?

Comment: @zero298 i edit the OP's question by adding running snippet and my answer also contains that, i recommend to save that in your bookmarks which help you when you want to provide an answer containing running snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging the Code snippet i found the solution by adding `slot-scope="i"` to the `tooltip` component like `<v-tooltip   slot-scope="i" right>` :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      bars: ['home', 'event', 'info']
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<div id="app" data-app>
  <v-item-group >
    <v-container grid-list-md>
      <v-layout wrap>
        <v-flex v-for="(n,i) in bars" :key="n" xs12 md4>
          <v-item     >
            <v-tooltip   slot-scope="i" right>
              <v-btn slot="activator">
                <v-icon>{{n}}</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
              <span>{{n}}</span>
            </v-tooltip>
          </v-item>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-item-group>

</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, when I try it in my code, I get es-lint warnings that 'i' is defined but never used (and it points to the 'i' in the v-for loop).  Is the syntax for how it's referenced inside the slot-scope correct?

Comment: Unfortunately the code does not run for me due to that error

Comment: try this `<v-flex v-for="n in bars" :key="n" xs12 md4>
          <v-item     >
            <v-tooltip   slot-scope="{active}" right>...`

Comment: I get the same error about how 'active' is defined but never used