# Centralize radio-group Vuetify

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I cannot centralize `v-radio-group`. Here's what I got:

```
<v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
  <v-form ref="form>

    <div v-if="question.question_type == 'YESNO' ">
          <v-radio-group v-model="answer">
            <v-layout>

              <v-flex>
                <v-radio
                value="Yes"
                label="Yes"
                ></v-radio>
              </v-flex>

              <v-flex>
                <v-radio
                value="No"
                label="No"
                ></v-radio>
              </v-flex>

            </v-layout>
          </v-radio-group>
        </div>   

  </v-form>
</v-container>
```

I tried setting classes 'text-xs-center' and 'justify-center' to form and div tags but it didn't help. I want this layout (radio buttons) to be in the middle of my form.

Comment: please provide a running example like [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094579/missing-a-default-scoped-slot/54097082#54097082)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add class named `flex-center` to your div element that wraps radio buttons group and add the following rule to your CSS :

```
.flex-center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  }
```

Full example :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      question: {
        question_type: 'YESNO'
      },
      answer: ''
    }
  }

})
```

```css
.flex-center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<div id="app" data-app>
  <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
    <v-form ref="form">

      <div v-if="question.question_type == 'YESNO'" class="flex-center">
        <v-radio-group v-model="answer">
          <v-layout>

            <v-flex>
              <v-radio value="Yes" label="Yes"></v-radio>
            </v-flex>

            <v-flex>
              <v-radio value="No" label="No"></v-radio>
            </v-flex>

          </v-layout>
        </v-radio-group>
      </div>

    </v-form>
  </v-container>



</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! That's what I've been looking for. Thank you!

Comment: OP apparently tried to do it without reading the relevant docs. Thus I posted more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the Vuetify way to do it seems to be like this:

```
<v-form>
  <v-radio-group row v-model="answer" class="justify-center">
    <v-radio value="Yes" label="Yes"></v-radio>
    <v-radio value="No" label="No"></v-radio>
  </v-radio-group>
</v-form>
```

So on `v-radio-group` add `row` prop, and then align buttons with `justify-center`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    answer: null
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container grid-list-xl>
        <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
          <v-form>
            <v-radio-group row v-model="answer" class="justify-center">
              <v-radio value="Yes" label="Yes"></v-radio>
              <v-radio value="No" label="No"></v-radio>
            </v-radio-group>
          </v-form>
        </v-container>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me -- maybe something has changed since you wrote this.  I fixed it by adding a style `.justify-center::v-deep .v-input--radio-group__input { justify-content: center; }`

Comment: @taxilian Thank you. Yes, my answer was originally for version 1.4 or something like that, so that version is pretty much outdated. You might write another answer for newer version if you like.