# How to Float Container at Bottom of Page in Vue?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm Currently working on a very Simple Website with VueJS.
I want to have a Container Floating at the Bottom of the Page, and i know how to do this with normal CSS, but because there are so many options in Vue and Vuetify i think that this Problem should be solveable with some sort of a tag.

My Current code is:

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <v-container class="test-container" grid-list-md text-xs-center fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xl12>
          <v-card dark color="primary">
            <v-card-text class="px-0">Test</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

      <v-layout row justify-space-around>
        <v-flex xs4>
          <v-card dark color="primary">
            <v-card-text>Test</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs4>
          <v-card dark color="accent">
            <v-card-text>Test</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

      <v-layout row justify-space-between>
        <v-flex xs4>
          <v-card dark color="primary">
            <v-card-text>Test</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs4>
          <v-card dark color="accent">
            <v-card-text>Test</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xl12>
          <v-text-field v-model="txtRequestText" box label="Test" type="text" prepend-inner-icon="place" append-icon="send" @click:append="sendRequest" @keyup.enter="sendRequest"></v-text-field>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

The last v-layout with the Textfield in it is the one that should be Displayed at the very Bottom of the Page.

I already tried using align-end on a v-container as well as setting the height of the container to 100% and then using align-end on one of the layouts, but that did not work at all.

Is there a Best Practice way of doing this, or should i just solve it with normal CSS instead?

-Edit-
Here you also have a working version of it:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.3.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.3.0/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<div id="app" class="content" data-app>
  <v-container class="test-container" grid-list-md text-xs-center fluid>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xl12>
        <v-card dark color="primary">
          <v-card-text class="px-0">Test</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>

    <v-layout row justify-space-around>
      <v-flex xs4>
        <v-card dark color="primary">
          <v-card-text>Test</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs4>
        <v-card dark color="accent">
          <v-card-text>Test</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>

    <v-layout row justify-space-between>
      <v-flex xs4>
        <v-card dark color="primary">
          <v-card-text>Test</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs4>
        <v-card dark color="accent">
          <v-card-text>Test</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>

    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xl12>
        <v-text-field box label="Test" type="text"></v-text-field>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide a running code like [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094579/missing-a-default-scoped-slot/54097082#54097082) in order to debug it

Answer (score 0):

I would say normal CSS. If you want the container to stay at the bottom I would suggest:

```
#id {
    display: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```